# Caching in LLBLGENPro

Tags: caching, repository, llblgenpro

We have a project that was implemented in linq to sql and is being migrated to LLBLGenPro runtime using the adapter pattern.

The first version of the app did a huge amount of caching, placing entire tables into the httpcache and then doing all the linking in the codebehind.  (sigh)

So you get something like :

```
from p in MyCacheObject.ProductPages
join cmpp in MyCacheObject.ProductContentMemberships on p.ProductPageId equals cmpp.ProductContentId
join pl in MyCacheObject.ProductPlans on cmpp.ProductLinkId equals pl.ProductPlanId
```

Now, in our new repository pattern, I can build such joins with prefetch paths.  You just call myRepository.GetProductPagesWithContentMemberships() and get a ProductPage entity with a collection of ProductContentMemberships.

That's great when we are talking to the db, but how do I sometimes pull from a collection of cached entities?  I want to cache the tables and then use them to build my complex objects.

I can make "get from cache" vs "get from db" a decision that the repo can make, but I'm hoping I don't have to write two entirely different implementations of GetProductPagesWithContentMemberships(): one to get from db and one to use the cache.

I'm hoping there is some kind of magic adapter that I can use  that will execute my linq against an object cache instead of sending it to SQL server.  Is there such a thing?

This post: http://www.llblgen.com/tinyforum/Messages.aspx?ThreadID=6265 hints that it is possible, but that's it.

Comment: Have you asked this on the LLBLGen support forum - you should get a fairly quick response from one of the support team.

Comment: I debated since I know Frans reads the stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer, I'm afraid, is "No"- there is no magic adapter that will do the caching for you, and LLBLGen does not support any form of caching other than using the Context object - but these are local to a user and session, and not global.

[Article by Frans Bouma about caching in ORM Mappers](http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2006/08/31/Why-a-cache-in-an-O_2F00_R-mapper-doesn_2700_t-make-it-fetch-data-faster_2E00_.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the answer.  I was hoping  that it would be easy to hook a custom adapter up to an object collection.  I suspect it is still possible, if I want to overload the adapter myself, but that's probably out of scope.

Comment: And in three years, things change: there is result set caching  and it's easy to use with linq code: https://www.llblgen.com/documentation/4.0/LLBLGen%20Pro%20RTF/Using%20the%20generated%20code/gencode_resultsetcaching.htm